# Set individual tabstops in vim

Tags: vim

How can I set individual tabstops in vim?

For example, I would like my first tab stop to be 30 chars wide and the rest to be 10 chars wide.

I find myself having to `set ts=30` because of just one column of text, forcing rows to overflow, making the tab-separated file harder to read.

Comment: Maybe a better place to ask : http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check the variable tabstop patch. I maintain it [here](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-mq-patches/blob/master/var_tabstops) and cheer at vim_dev to have it finally included.